# How to upload video to Facebook without user interaction? (or in background) after getting the open session

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

Before 30/April/2015,

this code was working fine for me. But now i am not getting "publish_actions" permission. So it redirects my application to facebook login page again and again. I know that Facebook has released its new api. But i am not getting any solution to get the video uploading permission.

```
if (![self.session hasGranted:@"publish_actions"]) {
    [self.session requestNewPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions", nil] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
        [self uploadVideotoFacebook:videoPath];
    }];
}
else{     
    [self uploadVideoToFacebook:videoPath];   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since April 30th 2015 every app which requests extended permissions need to got through login review.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/api-v1-deprecation
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

If you want to use the app solely to upload your videos (with your user), then you should be able to get the appropriate Access Token via the Graph Explorer. Login review is only necessary if other users should use the app as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your facebook application has publish_actions permission .

Go to the your application page and see if publish_actions permission is enabled or not .

After that , if you have the credentials for the account you're using this application to post videos for . Login to facebook with that account , go to settings , go to applications , go to your application and then see what permissions the application actually has .

Facebook allows users to edit the application permissions anytime , so if a user somehow turns off the POST permission , then you won't be able to post anything .